# How to define table column to be column of other table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

just starting to learn databases ...

I have two tables
     1. Table user => contain UserName[string], Id[int], Category[string]
     2. Table possible Category => contain Category[string]

I want to restrict on my SQL server ( express ) that the third column of the first table ( table user => Category column ) will contain possible value of the second table.

Is it possible ?
How can i do it ?

{ i mean that there is no possible way to set Category on the
user table that will not appear on the second table. }

Comment: Can you please explain

Comment: Take a look here  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: Since you didn't know what a foreign key is, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a [`foreign key` `constraint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms189049.aspx):

```
alter table [user] 
add constraint fk_category foreign key ([Category])
    references [possible Category]([Category]);
```